# Copying Public Folder calendar items to SharePoint calendar

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, outlook

I have a Public Folder calendar that we want to move away from. We'd like to copy everything in it to a SharePoint calendar. Everything is setup and I have successfully copied calendar items (appointments) over. However, when they're copied over the title of the appointment only displays as (no title). For some reason copying it over to the SharePoint calendar makes the title disappear.

My method for copying the items over was to click the Connect to Outlook button from the toolbar in the SharePoint calendar. It worked great and made it very easy to copy the items from one calendar to another using the Outlook interface. The only issue I've seen is this one where the title doesn't display.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it? Or perhaps is there another method I need to use to copy these items to the SharePoint calendar where the title does show up?